# Any halachos on repurposing arba minim?

Tags: halacha, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Am I allowed to add my hadasim (myrtle) to a bouquet after yom tov?

Or do anything with any of the arba minim after yom tov?

Comment: People have a minhag to eat the esrog and make besamaim from the haddasim (chabad.org -(d) Some have the custom to take hadasim (myrtle) leaves left from the lulav for the besamim. Since they were used for one mitzvah, they should be taken for another) . However a bouquet which is not a being used for a mitzvah may be different. Perhaps if it used to for Kavod Shabbos it would be better.

Comment: The day after you use any of them for the mitzvah they may not be used for anything else. Once they are holy for the day you used it, it is holy bein hashmashos (twilight). And since days overlap during twilight, once the 4 minim are holy bein hashmashos, they are holy the next day. But, at the second tzeis hakokhavim, they may be used for anything. The actual answers you got so far seem to focus on what is an appropriate use, not strictly what is permissible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a nice idea which is to use the object used for a mitzva for another one, e.g., I have seen

- some use the etrog for *besamim* (spices) during havdala, by planting cloves into the etrog
- people often burn the four species before Pesach together with the *hamets*

Beyond this you can also

- make etrog jam
- use the *hadasim* for a bouquet
- see [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1641900/jewish/What-Should-I-Do-with-My-Holiday-Lulav-and-Etrog-Set.htm) at chabad.org for more ideas

The only halachot I know of is not dispose of the four species in a degrading way, e.g., OU writes (bottom of [here](https://www.ou.org/holidays/halacha-lmaaseh-on-arba-minim/))

> You may dispose of a lulav in any way that is not degrading. So, you
> may drop it into a field or put it on a lawn–unless animals might eat
> it or step on it or if it will be subject to poor treatment before it
> decays. Don’t dispose of a lulav or etrog directly into the garbage.
> Burn, bury, or wrap them in a bag or one layer of plastic and you may
> throw it into normal garbage.

(see also [here](https://www.aish.com/atr/Disposing_of_the_Four_Species.html))

Comment: Warning against esrog jam or any other use of esrogim grown for the mitzvah... Check with an expert first. They use HUGE amounts of insecticide to grow esrogim, since every spot on an esrog detracts from its value, and the vast majority aren't eaten. Insecticide can soak deeply into the fruit.